# How to efficiently find a loop between two nodes in a directed graph?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, search-problem

Given two nodes in a directed graph, how can I find a loop (if exists) that pass these two nodes? The loop cannot pass a node more than once. And if there isn't such a loop, how to efficiently determines it?

Comment: Look up *topological sort*. Here's the rough sketch of what I've seen. I believe it has linear overhead: 0. Declare an empty set called Z.
1. Put all nodes into the same pool of nodes. Call this set W.
2. Call the node in W with the largest number of dependents (ie, children) LN. If LN has a child in Z, then there is a cycle and we quit. Otherwise, we put LN into Z.
3. Goto step (2) and continue until either a cycle is discovered or W is empty. I may be missing something. But the key point is that by just looking at

Comment: I think this can tell if there is a cycle, but cannot return a cycle that passes two specific nodes.

Answer (score 9):

This problem has been shown to be NP-complete in the following paper:

> S. Fortune, J. Hopcroft, J. Wyllie:
>   "The directed subgraph homeomorphism problem"
>   Theoretical Computer Science 10 (1980), pp. 111-121